# How do delegate methods work in Swift?

Tags: ios, oop, swift, delegates, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to learn how to program location into apps, and this whole chunk of code just really confused me with the locationManager and delegates. I don't get at all what's going on when you declare a function called locationManager. You are defining this function, locationManager, right? With 2 parameters. So what exactly is calling this locationManager? When going through the [Complete iOS Developer Course](https://www.udemy.com/complete-ios-developer-course/), he takes this locationManager snippet and copy pastes it without explaining the principles behind what you're doing when copying and pasting it. Is there some line of code that calls "locationManager(...)"? If so, where does this happen? My brain keeps thinking that if it's a function that's inherited from a superclass, CLLocationManagerDelegate, wouldn't you have to override it in order to get it to work? And could you give some intuition on how delegates work exactly?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



@IBOutlet var myMap : MKMapView!

var manager:CLLocationManager!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // Core Location
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()




}


func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error:NSError)
{
    println(error)
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These delegate methods, defined in the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol, are called by the `CLLocationManager` object that you instantiated and are referencing in the `manager` variable. So, you've instantiated the `CLLocationManager` object, you've asked it to inform you when there are location updates, and it does that by calling these delegate methods you've implemented.

You say:

> My brain keeps thinking that if it's a function that's inherited from a superclass, `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, wouldn't you have to override it in order to get it to work?

The `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is not a class. It is a "protocol". It defines what functions the `delegate` object (in this case, your view controller) may/should implement. So, there's nothing to override.

Comment: Okay so these delegate methods are optional, right? So how does Swift know that I've implemented these methods in my code?

Comment: In this case, it's relying on the `respondsToSelector` method that `NSObject` provides (and from which all of these Cocoa Touch classes descend). If it was pure Swift there's another mechanism to confirm conformance to a protocol's optional methods (see _Optional Protocol Requirements_ discussion in [The Swift Language: Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)), but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: @rb612 you might refer to the [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html) discussions in the Core Competencies docs, or the [Programming in Objective-C: Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). It's Objective-C focused, but the principles are the same.